# What is kind in kubernetes YAML meant?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm very new to kubernetes .What is meant for kind: Deployment?. What are the different kind. Is there any document available for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`kind` represents the type of Kubernetes objects to be created while using the `yaml` file.

`kind: Deployment` represents the Kubernetes [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) object.

You can use the following command to view different supported objects:

```
kubectl api-resources
```

You can also review the [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/) for detailed overview regarding the Kubernetes objects.

Comment: To add further, there can't be an exhaustive list as `CRD` are also `kind` objects and they can vary depending on definition of the CRDs in the cluster.

Comment: "API reference" is a dead link, searching at kubernetes.io gives [API Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/) and [The Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/)

Answer (score 2):

In a Kubernetes YAML file, the kind field is a fundamental directive that specifies the type or kind of Kubernetes resource you are defining within the file. This field is crucial because it informs Kubernetes how to interpret and handle the resource described in the YAML configuration.

The kind directive is used to identify the intended Kubernetes resource type and is used as part of the API version and resource definition. The combination of kind and apiVersion helps Kubernetes understand how to process the YAML file and what kind of object to create, update, or manage within the cluster.

Here is a more detailed explanation of the kind field in Kubernetes YAML, along with code snippets for illustration:

### Purpose of the kind Field:

---

The kind field serves several key purposes:

**Resource Type Identification:** It identifies the specific Kubernetes resource type you are defining, such as a Deployment, Service, Pod, ConfigMap, or any other resource type supported by Kubernetes.

**Resource Behavior Specification:** It informs Kubernetes how to handle the resource. Different resource types have distinct behaviors, rules, and fields associated with them. Kubernetes relies on kind to determine how to manage and operate the resource.

Example Usage of kind:
Here are some examples of common kind values and their explanations:

### Deployment:

`kind: Deployment` is used to define a Kubernetes Deployment resource. Deployments manage the lifecycle of Pods and enable scaling and rolling updates.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-image:latest
```

### Service:

`kind: Service` is used to define a Kubernetes Service resource. Services provide network access to a set of Pods and perform load balancing.
yaml
Copy code
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: my-service
spec:
selector:
app: my-app
ports:

- protocol: TCP
  port: 80
  targetPort: 80
  Pod:

`kind: Pod` is used to define a Kubernetes Pod. Pods are the smallest deployable units and can contain one or more containers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-1
    image: my-image-1:latest
  - name: container-2
    image: my-image-2:latest
```

### ConfigMap:

`kind: ConfigMap` is used to define a Kubernetes ConfigMap resource for storing configuration data.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

The kind field is essential because it ensures that Kubernetes interprets the YAML configuration correctly and applies the desired behavior to the resource. Each kind corresponds to a specific resource type, and the associated fields and rules for that resource type are expected in the YAML definition.

Comment: Thanks for your summary, this is better than the accepted answer.